# Could not find the correct Provider<AuthProvider> above this SignUpIdols Widget

Tags: flutter

I know there is many answer on flutter provider but I cannot find my answer after hours of debugging please help me

I have a widget which is SignUpIdols

```
 Widget signupidolsUI(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
```

> **This is the issues final auth = Provider.of(context);**

My AuthProvider Class

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Status _loggedInStatus = Status.NotLoggedIn;
  Status _registeredInStatus = Status.NotRegistered;

  Status get loggedInStatus => _loggedInStatus;
  Status get registeredInStatus => _registeredInStatus;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> register(
      String name, String email, String password) async {
    _registeredInStatus = Status.Registering;

    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    var result;

    users
        .add({'name': name, 'email': email, 'password': password})
        .then((value) => () {
              result = {
                'status': true,
                'message': 'Successful',
                'user': 'Register Successful'
              };

              _registeredInStatus = Status.Registered;
            })
        .catchError((error) => () {
              result = {'status': true, 'message': 'Error', 'user': '$error'};
            });

    return result;
  }
}
```

Error I face
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show where are you injecting(providing) your `AuthProvider` and where are you trying to read it.  Like the full code between those two points, also if it is inside a dialog ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help after I inject MultiProvider() on my main MyApp it's works

Answer (score 0):

I fix it after I inject multiprovider on my main app its works

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(create: (BuildContext context) {
            return AuthProvider();
          }),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
```